# How to ignore files in Git that are like _ReSharper

Tags: git

I want to ingore any file/folder that has:

_ReSharper

in the file or folder in my .gitignore file, is this possible?

I tried:

*ReSharper*

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the exact name you want to the `.gitignore`,  in this case add

```
_ReSharper
```

`_` is not a special character in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 1):

I read your question as asking whether you can ignore all files and directories that contain `_ReSharper` as a substring of their name, in which case you can add the following line to your `.gitignore`:

```
*_ReSharper*
```

Comment: I tried that, maybe the issue is that file already exists in the repo (its a modification), so it will then not get ignored right?

Comment: Yes, the [documentation for `gitignore`](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitignore.html) says "Files already tracked by git are not affected; see the NOTES below for details."